# How i can make QLabel clickable?

Tags: c++, qt

Im started learning Qt.

So I want to do a QLable clickable. How can I do this?

ClickableLabel.h

```
#ifndef CLICKABLELABEL_H
#define CLICKABLELABEL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

class ClickableLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClickableLabel(QWidget *parrent = nullptr);
    ~ClickableLabel();

signals:
    void clicked();

public:
    void mousePressedEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

    using QLabel::QLabel;
};

#endif // CLICKABLELABEL_H
```

I searched for information on Google, but that code doesn't work. So I don't know how to fix it.
Please help.

ClickableLabel.cpp

```
#include "clickablelabel.h"

ClickableLabel::ClickableLabel(QWidget *parrent)
    : QLabel(parrent)
{

}

ClickableLabel::~ClickableLabel()
{

}

void ClickableLabel::mousePressedEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    emit clicked();
}
```

I promoted my custom label so idk what to do more.

[ui form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOEJd.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to use QPushButton.